# How to evaluate the log-posterior in pymc3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I want to evaluate the log posterior (ideally  separately the log prior and log likelihood) values at sample points and at some manually entered points (e.g. the true parameter value points for synthetic datasets). How can I achieve this in PyMC3?

Update:
I've found the `logp()` method, however it's not very convenient to use for multiple points. Is are there some standard / idiomatic approach?

Update:
This `[y.logp(trace[i]) for i in range(len(trace))]` works, but is superslow.

Update:
Slowness was caused by the fact that `y` is the observed random variable, calling `logp` method of the model works fast.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've asked a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565385/how-to-calculate-log-posterior-of-a-gp-over-a-trace-in-pymc3) and feel free to post a nice reply to help me out and also claim a point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the reality is that it's best to ask PyMC3 related questions on their [discourse forum.](https://discourse.pymc.io/)

So [to get the values of log-posterior after sampling](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/evaluate-logposterior-at-sample-points/235/10) use

`logp = mvg_model.logp
lnp = np.array([logp(trace.point(i,chain=c)) for c in trace.chains for i in range(len(trace))])`

[To save them during sampling](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/how-to-save-logp-values-during-sampling/793) use

```

```
with model:
   llk = pm.Deterministic(likelihood_name, model.logpt)
```

```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'logpt'. Did you mean: 'logp'?`. Maybe something has changed since PyMC3.

Comment: @Galen Logpt with a "t" is not a typo. Most likely the API has changed since 2018. I haven't been doing MCMC since 2019, so cannot tell. The code  was something that was used in PyMC3 code (you can see for yourself if you follow the last link in the answer).